# Elasticsearch query over huge data

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, bucket

We have over 100 million data store in Elasticsearch.

1. Dataset are too much to be fully loaded into our service memory.
2. Each data has a column called amount. **The search is to find out several (sometimes over 10 thousand) target data that their sum of the amount equals or close to an input value.**

Below is out **current solution**:

1. We merge the 100 million data input 4000 buckets by using ES's bucket. Each bucket's amount is the sum of every data it contains.
2. We load the 4000 buckets into our service. Afterwards we find out the solution mentioned above based on the 4000 buckets.

The obvious disadvantage is the lack of accuracy. The difference between the sum of results we find and the input target is sometimes quite large.

We are three young guys lack of experience, **we need some instructions**.

Comment: can you share some example documents and your query please

Comment: And a sample document would also be nice